# loss of index when using pd.merge_asof()

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, merge

I have a question in respect of pd.merge_asof and indexing.

First of all I am creating a data frame with the columns/data I need and then sorting it as follows:

```
df1 = df[['A','B','C']].sort_values('B')

df1.head()
```

The head shows that the index from df has been carried forward in to df1 (the index is a date).

Next I perform pd.merge_asof as follows:

```
df2 = pd.merge_asof(df, df3, left_on='B', right_on='Z')
```

If I check the head of df2 however, the date index is now lost. I need to have this carried forward in to df2 (from df/df1) as I will re-sort the data back in to date order (it is important for what I am doing).

Any ideas how I can do this in a simple manner?

Thank you as always!

Paul

Comment: Does you df2 have multiple indexes? if you only have one and it is a sorted `datetime` then can you do `df2 = pd.merge_asof(df, df3, left_index=True, right_index=True)`. If `datetime` is not your index then can you try resetting your index to sorted `datetime` and redo the join? Please make sure the `dtype` is `datetime` before you set as index and merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you merge and do not merge on any part of the original indices, the index loses its relevance. You join rows from different DataFrames, so how would you know which index to choose?

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,2,3]}, index=list('abc'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'bar': [1,2,3]}, index=list('xyz'))

pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='foo', right_on='bar')

   foo  bar
0    1    1    # Should the index be 'a' or 'x'?
1    2    2    #                     'b' or 'y'?
2    3    3    #                     'c' or 'z'?
```

If you need the index to come along in the merge, remove the ambiguity by making it a column with `reset_index`

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), left_on='foo', right_on='bar')

  index_x  foo index_y  bar
0       a    1       x    1
1       b    2       y    2
2       c    3       z    3
```